# Visual Basic - Start process or tasks after a specific delay

Tags: vb.net, hyperlink

```vb
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
      Process.Start("https://google.com/")
      'I want to wait here for 20 seconds. Then I want him to open the yandex.
      Process.Start("https://yandex.com/")    
    End Sub
```

Can you help me how can I do. Thanks for all.

Comment: You need to use `sleep(XXX)`. check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.sleep?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example you can see how start a process after a specific delay.
In your case is launch a browser but you can use in other scenarios as a technique delay related.
Take a look on code and improve it based in your necessities.

```
Event TimerDone()
Private Sub ProcessStartAfterDelay(Optional ByVal url As String = "", Optional interval As Integer = 2000)

    Dim tmr As System.Windows.Forms.Timer = New System.Windows.Forms.Timer
    AddHandler tmr.Tick, Sub()
                             tmr.Stop()
                             tmr.Dispose()
                             If url.Length > 0 Then
                                 Try
                                     Process.Start(url)
                                     RaiseEvent TimerDone()
                                 Catch ex As Exception
                                     Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString)
                                 End Try
                             End If
                         End Sub

    tmr.Interval = interval
    tmr.Start()

End Sub


Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim index As Integer = 0
    Dim delay As Integer = 3000
    Dim listOfUrls As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)({"https://google.com/",
                                                            "https://yandex.com/",
                                                            "https://it.yahoo.com/",
                                                            "https://www.wikipedia.org/"})


    ' First launch need to be here with delay > 0 important!
    ProcessStartAfterDelay(listOfUrls(index), 1)

    AddHandler Me.TimerDone, Sub()
                                 index += 1
                                 If index < listOfUrls.Count Then
                                     ProcessStartAfterDelay(listOfUrls(index), delay)
                                 Else
                                     RemoveHandler Me.TimerDone, Nothing
                                 End If
                             End Sub



End Sub
```

Comment: I’ve slimmed the code, re-tray again as is more compact ;)

Comment: How can we do more than 2 links? For example, when you start to use it for 100 links, after the first two, it all opens up at once.

Comment: There is several techniques, try starting with a custom event. Raise this event when timer is done then intercept them to start the next one

Comment: can you make an example for me to examine?